# 405 error (Method Not Allowed) on Web API get

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, getjson

I'm having a frustrating problem when I try to make a call to my Web API controller method with $.getJSON : it always ends up with the following message being displayed in the console : "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)"

Here's my controller :

```
using MyProject.Domain;
using MyProject.WebApp.Session;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MyProject.WebApp.ApiControllers.Favorites
{
    public class FavoriteArticlesController : BaseController<FavoriteArticle, Guid>
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public object SetFavorite(Guid articleId, bool isFavorite)
        {
            try
            {
                if (isFavorite)
                {
                    var favorite = new FavoriteArticle
                    {
                        UserId = UserInfo.GetUserId(),
                        ArticleId = articleId
                    };
                    _repo.Upsert(favorite);
                }
                else
                {
                    var favorite = _repo.GetAll()
                        .First(fa => fa.ArticleId.CompareTo(articleId) == 0);
                    _repo.Delete(favorite.Id);
                }
                _repo.Commit();
                return new { Success = true, Error = (string)null };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return new { Success = false, Error = ex.Message };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In case that is relevant in any way, BaseController naturally derives from ApiController. Here's the code if needed :

```
using MyProject.Data.Repository;
using MyProject.Data.Services;
using MyProject.Domain;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyProject.WebApp.ApiControllers
{
    public class BaseController<TEntity, TKey> : ApiController
        where TEntity : class, IEntity<TKey>, new()
    {
        protected UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        protected Repository<TEntity, TKey> _repo;

        protected BaseController()
        {
            _unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork();
            _repo = _unitOfWork.GetRepository<TEntity, TKey>();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's one of the functions that make the call :

```
$.fn.bindFavoriteArticle = function () {
    this.click(function () {
        var link = $(this);
        $.getJSON('/api/FavoriteArticles/SetFavorite', { ajax: true, articleId: link.attr('data-target-id'), isFavorite: true }, function (response) {
            if (response.Success === true) {
                link.children('i').removeClass('fa-heart-o')
                    .addClass('fa-heart');
                link.attr('data-toggle', 'unfavoriteArticle')
                    .unbind('click')
                    .bindUnfavoriteArticle();
            } else {
                // TODO : use bootstrap alert messages
                alert(response.Error);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

I saw here and there that the route configuration could be the source of the problem, so here's the content of RouteConfig.cs :

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace MyProject.WebApp
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "ApiDefault",
                url: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "SubscriptionsController", action = "GetSelectList", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea of what's going on ? I feel like there's a lot I'm missing concerning how Web APIs work...

Comment: Try to take link.attr('data-target-id') to '/api/FavoriteArticles/SetFavorite'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the other answers, the code configured the wrong routes. For web api configure the `WebApiConfig`

```
public static class WebApiConfig {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config) {
        // Web API routes

        //Enable Attribute routing is they are being used.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        //Convention based routes.

        //Matches GET /api/FavoriteArticles/SetFavorite
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultActionApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        //Matches GET /api/FavoriteArticles
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Make sure that it is configured before MVC routes.

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    // Pass a delegate to the Configure method.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    //...other configurations
}
```

Some advice about refactoring the controller to be a little more restful. Try to return `IHttpActionResult` from actions. simplifies the framework and give you more control of how the response is returned.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/favoritearticles"]
public class FavoriteArticlesController : BaseController<FavoriteArticle, Guid> {


    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{articleId:guid}")] //Matches POST api/favoritearticles/{articleId:guid}
    public IHttpActionResult SetFavorite(Guid articleId) {            
        var favorite = new FavoriteArticle
        {
            UserId = UserInfo.GetUserId(),
            ArticleId = articleId
        };
        _repo.Upsert(favorite);
        _repo.Commit();
        return Ok(new { Success = true, Error = (string)null });
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    [Route("{articleId:guid}")] //Matches DELETE api/favoritearticles/{articleId:guid}
    public IHttpActionResult RemoveFavorite(Guid articleId) {            
        var favorite = _repo.GetAll()
            .First(fa => fa.ArticleId == articleId);

        if(favorite == null) return NotFound();

        _repo.Delete(favorite.Id);
        _repo.Commit();
        return Ok(new { Success = true, Error = (string)null });
    }
}
```

Controllers should be as lean as possible so even the above should be slimmed down even more via an injected service into the controller.

Error handling is a cross-cutting concern and should also be extracted and handled via the framework's extensibility points.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was indeed my problem and your advice has been really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You are configuring api routes inside the `RouteConfig` rather than `WebApiConfig`.

You need a `WebApiConfig.cs` file inside your `App_Start` folder with this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

...so you can remove the `routes.MapRoute()` for `api/{controller}/{action}/{id}` inside your `RouteConfig.cs`.

Then in your `Global.asax` you call it like this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas(); // only if you have areas...

    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

With this, both links should work fine for your controller sample:

```
/api/FavoriteArticles?articleId=a7d944f7-66be-4200-9b89-26eda5173dca&isFavorite=true
/api/FavoriteArticles/SetFavorite?articleId=a7d944f7-66be-4200-9b89-26eda5173dca&isFavorite=true
```

The way you are calling it via `jQuery` is correct, there is no need to change it at all.

Comment: The second link wont work are there is not route template that takes the action name

Comment: That is most odd. Ok. I figured it out. it is matching `SetFavorite` to `{id}` placeholder in the default template and matching the query string. which makes it a false positive. If you were to give the action an id parameter you would see  that it is right.

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Comment: @ZipionLive you're welcome, it took me some time to figure out you were using `RouteConfig`, I even created a sample project, but I'm glad you could solve your problem.

Comment: @ZipionLive also, I think my answer should be marked as accepted rather than Nkosi, I deserve since I posted my answer about three hours before him. He just posted my answer with some advices about route attributes, which is nice (actually he also recognizes I answered before). I think he should have edited my answer with his advices instead of posting the same answer three hours later. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

I believe by default JSON requests block GET methods to avoid JSON Hijacking. Try either converting your method to a POST (and update the ajax call) or alter your current function return to

```
return Json(new { Success = true, Error = (string)null }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```